# How to calculate the cumulative density of a bump function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How would I go about calculating the integral
$$\int_{1/4}^x \exp\left(\frac{-1}{1-16(t-\frac{1}{2})^2}\right)dt,$$ where we assume $\frac{1}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{4}$? Thanks!

Comment: no reason to expect an explicit antiderivative in any closed form

Comment: No reason to expect, but one can hope. I saw a post with a related problem, but it was calculating the entire area of the bump.

Comment: Well, the integral of $e^{-x^2} dx$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is well known, but the antiderivative is not a traditional elementary function, they had to make up a new name for it (erf of some such). I expect the same here, but do not know whether you can write your thing in terms of erf.

Comment: Oh, I don't care about elementary functions, necessarily.

Comment: **Hint:** Try rewriting it as $\dfrac12\displaystyle\int_0^1\exp\dfrac1{x^2-1}~dx$, and then approximate the integrand with $a(1-bx^2)$, where $a\approx\dfrac13$ and $b\approx1$.

Comment: No, I need this exact function for my purposes. I'm looking for a smooth function that is 0 for all values less than 1/4 and 1 for all values greater than 3/4. CDF of the normalized bump function seemed to me the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for your integral because, plainly speaking, there are no “incomplete”

[Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). By letting $y=4\bigg(t-\dfrac12\bigg),~$ and then $y=\cos u,~$ the integral finally becomes,

for $x=\dfrac34,\quad\dfrac{K_1\Big(\frac12\Big)-K_0\Big(\frac12\Big)}{4\sqrt e}.~$ But since the integral expression of the Bessel $K$ function

requires that both its integration limits be fixed integer multiples of $\dfrac\pi2,~$ expressing our function

for a random variable *x* becomes unfeasible, even in terms of such special functions as the ones

mentioned above.

Comment: Sounds about right. Thanks!